# How to use Google DFA (Google Publisher Tag) in SPA?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-dfp

I am using Google DFA (gpt.js) in Angular.

The first time an ad is displaying fine but second time it gives null error.

I have directive which has the following method, called in `OnInit` method:

```
addGoogleAd() {
  const googletag: any = window['googletag'] || {};

  if (window['googletag'] && googletag.apiReady) {
    googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];

    googletag.cmd.push(() => {
      googletag.pubads().setTargeting('site', 'weatherinnovations');
      googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();

      googletag.defineSlot('/xx/weather_innovations', [[160, 600]], 'div-gpt-ad-xx-1')
        .setTargeting('position', ['s1']).addService(googletag.pubads());
      googletag.defineSlot('/xx/weather_innovations', [[300, 250]], 'div-gpt-ad-xx-2')
        .setTargeting('position', ['s2']).addService(googletag.pubads());
      googletag.defineSlot('/xx/weather_innovations', [[300, 250]], 'div-gpt-ad-xx-3')
        .setTargeting('position', ['s3']).addService(googletag.pubads());
      googletag.defineSlot('/76643716/weather_innovations', [[728, 90]], 'div-gpt-ad-xx-4')
        .setTargeting('position', ['s4']).addService(googletag.pubads());
      googletag.defineSlot('/xx/weather_innovations', [[728, 90]], 'div-gpt-ad-xx-5')
        .setTargeting('position', ['s5']).addService(googletag.pubads());

      googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs(true, true);
      googletag.enableServices();
    });
    googletag.display(this.id);
  }
}
```

The dashboard loads and displays ad, but when I return back from another component it gives the following error:

> pubads_impl_265.js:1 Exception in queued GPT command TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'setTargeting' of null

I consoled the `googletag` and is not empty, and has same content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was not descriptive to debug it fast. Now, I am destroying the previously created slots before creating more and this solved the problem. Use the line right before `googletag.cmd.push`

```
googletag.destroySlots();
```